# Implement a speed gauge in Appcelerator Studio

Tags: appcelerator, tss

How can I create a speed gauge in Appcelerator Studio? Using only `view.xml`, `view.tss` and `view.js`? Because I am not using other libraries like `d3.js`.

Answer (score 0):

"Speed gauge" is a bit vague, but depending on how complicated of a solution you're looking for, using something like D3 might be the best, and quickest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, i use a image and and set a dynamic rotation. Just use [2DMatrix](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.2DMatrix)

Example: .js

```
var rotateFirst = Titanium.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate(90);
$.imageTest.transform = rotateFirst;
```

----- .xml

```
<View id="test">
  <ImageView id="imageTest"/>
</View>
```

---- .tss

```
"#imageTest":{
    image:"/images/home/hello.png",
    width:"40%",
    opacity:1,
    left:"7%",
    anchorPoint : {
        x : 0.5,
        y : 0.5
   }
}
```